# ruby require not working

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.9

I'm new to ruby, but I'm working on my first ruby program. It currently has two files, one is a library of functions (`xgync.rb` stored in `lib`) the other is the executable `xgync` stored in 'bin'. (Project visible here https://bitbucket.org/jeffreycwitt/xgync/src) I've also created a symlink to my `/usr/local/bin/xgync` so that I can write the command xgync `{arguments}` from anywhere in the terminal.

The problem seems to be that `bin/xgync` depends on the library `lib/xgync.rb`. I've written this dependency in `bin/xgync` as follows:

```
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')
require "xgync"
```

However, i keep getting the following error:

```
/Users/JCWitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- xgync (LoadError)
from /Users/JCWitt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/bin/xgync:4:in `<main>'
```

can you see anything wrong with what I've written? Could the symlink be somehow messing things up?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using *ruby 1.9.x* you don't usually alter the path with the `$:.unshift` when requiring other files in your project.

Instead the best practice is to use `require_relative` instead.

```
require_relative '../lib/xgync.rb'
```

`require_relative` requires files relative to the file you are currently editing.

But the error you experience appears, because you require a file, which does not exist:

- **bin/xgync**
- **lib/xgync.rb**

These are the files in your project according to your question, and the code-excerpt is from **bin/xgync** you extended the path to look for files in **lib/** but you try to `require 'xgync'` which is a file, that is not present in **lib/**, so if you wanted to use this method (instead of `require_relative` you would have to use `require 'xgync.rb'`.

Comment: success with `require_relative` path!!! thank you. Thanks for the explanation as well.