# Why I couldn't require 'string.rb' file in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, rubygems, require

I am implementing gem, I want to add some custom methods to String class. So, I created in 'lib' directory sub-directory 'core_ext', and placed there file 'string.rb'.

string.rb contains:

```
class String
  def custom_method
    some_action
  end
end
```

In my main file I made:

```
require 'core_ext/string.rb'
```

but it doesn't have any influence on String class,

If I change file's name to some other name, like 'my_string.rb' and change line with require, everything will work properly. Why I can't use 'string.rb' as name of file?

Comment: You don't need to require `string.rb` for your code to work. Requiring tells Ruby to load that class, and the String class is already loaded. You code seems like it should work. I just tested it and it worked fine. Can you be more specific about what "not working" means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby require not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600170/ruby-require-not-working)  (try `require_relative`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a file called `core_ext/string` that's already loaded anywhere else, this one is considered loaded as well. You may need to come up with a different name.

The `require_relative` feature of Ruby 1.9 that p11y points out is a much better solution.

Comment: Yeah, you was right. I have 'base_gem' and current gem, current gem is using 'base_gem'. Base gem also has 'core_ext/string.rb' and requires it, but strange that require think that it's equal paths, do you know why it think in such way?

Comment: @dolgishev try `load 'core_ext/string.rb'`. `load` is not smart and happily loads files twice.

Comment: @steenslag Using `load` is a really heavy-handed approach and is probably a bad idea.